# Php, how to swap two associative array KEYs?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this input:

```
array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 3,
    'd' => 4
);
```

I want to get this:

```
array(
    'a' => 1,    
    'c' => 3,
    'b' => 2,
    'd' => 4
);
```

as you can see, keys changed, not their values. I know there is no even order in associative arrays - in my case it is important. So, any solution?

Comment: Have you tried something to get to your goal?

Comment: Is there an *algorithm* to set the order, or is just an arbitrary order you define over a few keys?

Comment: There's a function in php that would help you. Just read the documentations.

Comment: no, its arbitrary definied

Comment: What  rules are you using to get from the input array to the required order in the output array? I assume there are rules that you will tell us? We are not required to work them out? As long as you tell us what the mapping is, and the sort order then we can, most likely, come up with a way.

Comment: @JohnSmith my solution is the shortest and simplest it could be :)

Comment: What are the next values four values from 'e' to 'h'? Which of the answers supplied work?

Comment: There are a couple of possible series - from limited data, using keys: 1) alternate key sequences with every other key at interval 2,  starting 'a' then 'c etc. Also, 'b', 'd'. Hmm... Using the values gives this sequence as well. Is this coincidence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

another solution, for arbitrary

```
$array = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 3,
    'd' => 4
);

print_r($array);

$myNewOrder = ['a','c','d','b'];
$result = [];
foreach($myNewOrder as $key){
    $result[$key] = $array[$key];
}

$array = $result;

print_r($array);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 2
    [c] => 3
    [d] => 4
)
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [c] => 3
    [d] => 4
    [b] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution requires the use of the `array_insert_before`-function from http://eosrei.net/articles/2011/11/php-arrayinsertafter-arrayinsertbefore (I am not certain about copyrights, so I do not copy his function body here).

Then you could simply declare another two functions:

```
function replaceKey(array &$arr, $keyFrom, $keyTo) {
    array_insert_before($keyFrom, $arr, $keyTo, $arr[$keyFrom]);
    unset($arr[$keyFrom]);
}

function swapKeys(array &$arr, $key1, $key2) {
    // $arr = array(x => a, y => b, z => c), $key1 = x, $key2 = z

    // generate a random value for "tmp" that is not a key of any element in $arr
    for($tmpName = 0; isset($arr[$tmpName]); $tmpName++);

    // array(tmp => a, y => b, z => c);
    replaceKey($arr, $key1, $tmpName);

    // array(tmp => a, y => b, x => c);
    replaceKey($arr, $key2, $key1);

    // array(z => a, y => b, x => c);
    replaceKey($arr, $tmpName, $key2);
}
```

No guarantee, not tested! This is only a concept!

Answer (score 1):

As told in comments, this is an arbitry order, defined by you. Saying this, here you have a simple (but not scalable) approach using an auxiliar array.

```
<?php
    $start = array(
        "a" => 1,
        "b" => 2,
        "c" => 3,
        "d" => 4
    );

    $aux = array(
        "a" => $start["a"],
        "c" => $start["b"],
        "b" => $start["c"],
        "d" => $start["d"],
    );

    $start = $aux;
    var_dump($start);
    die();
?>
```

---

This is a little bit more scalable and programatical approach. I used an aux array, and a translate one.

```
<?php
    $start = array(
        "a" => 1,
        "b" => 2,
        "c" => 3,
        "d" => 4
    );

    $translate = array(
        "a" => "a",
        "b" => "c",
        "c" => "b",
        "d" => "d"
    );

    $aux = array();

    foreach($translate as $old => $new) {
        $aux[$new] = $start[$old];
    }

    $start = $aux;
    var_dump($start);
    die();
?>
```

Comment: I'm not proud of this chunk of code, but you have to accept that you have a weird requirement..

Answer (score 1):

[EDITED] New answer -  If arbitrary defined , odd first, even last

```
$b=array_flip($array);
foreach ($b as $k => $v) {
    ($k % 2 == 0)?$even[$k]=$v:$odd[$k]=$v;
}
$n=$odd+$even;
$n=array_flip($n);
//print_r($n);
```

Shortest and sweetest (previous- if not arbitrary defined)

```
$b=array_flip($array);
shuffle($b);
$new=array_flip($b);
//print_r($new);
```

Comment: The OP asked for arbitrary **defined** order. This is undefined order.

Comment: @JoaquínO improved answer :)

Comment: even odd? :/ isn't it. i am confused bit. first it was random, now its even odd. one of them should have been correct. clear me out :)

Comment: OP wants to define an arbitrary order. Not random, not 'greater than', not even-odd, not any *logical* rule. That's what I understand from his question. Sorry if I'm wrong.

Comment: @JoaquínO nothing happens on its own, so tell me how we can compute without an algorithm :/ . now i am confused more. my first answer was so arbitrary that no one could even guess..

Comment: It was not arbitrary, it was random. User could not define which order he wanted. Anyway, try asking for more info to the OP in the question comments so he can clearify this.

Comment: we provide answer depending what the OP says :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the function that does what you need.

```
function shuffle_assoc($array) {

    $keys = array_keys($array);
    shuffle($keys);

    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $new[$key] = $array[$key];
    }

    $array = $new;    
    return $array;
}
```

If OP wants to provide an specific order:

```
function shuffle_assoc_by_order($array, $order) {

    foreach($order as $key) {
        $new[$key] = $array[$key];
    }

    $array = $new;    
    return $array;
}
```

use: `shuffle_assoc_by_order($input, ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']);`

Comment: The OP asked for arbitrary **defined** order. This is undefined order.

Comment: @JoaquínO so OP will provide order by some kind of input? OP didn't clarify question I think.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the answers, it wasnt as easy as I thought. I wrote a general function for it:

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public final static function swapAssociativeKeys (array &$array, $key1, $key2)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++)
    {
        if (array_keys($array)[$i] == $key1)
        {
            $key1at = $i;
        }
        if (array_keys($array)[$i] == $key2)
        {
            $key2at = $i;
        }
    }
    if ($key1at > $key2at)
    {
        $i = $key1at;
        $key1at = $key2at;
        $key2at = $i;
    }

    $order = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++)
    {
        if ($i == $key1at)
        {
            $order[] = array_keys($array)[$key2at];
        }
        else
        {
            if ($i == $key2at)
            {
                $order[] = array_keys($array)[$key1at];
            }
            else
            {
                $order[] = array_keys($array)[$i];
            }
        }
    }

    $return = array();
    foreach ($order as $i)
    {
        $return[$i] = $array[$i];
    }
    return $return;
}
```